# Observe live data objects in fragment using activity context?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-livedata, android-viewmodel

I'm using navigation bottom with shared `ViewModel` with all fragments inside navigation bottom but it throws this exception when recall fragment second time

**`java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot add the same observer with different lifecycles`**

I have tried to make all observers attached to activity not to it's fragment as below

1-Declare viewModel in fragemt

```
viewModel = activity?.run { 
          ViewModelProviders.of(this,viewModelFactory).get(SharedViewModel::class.java)
} ?: throw Exception("Invalid Activity")
```

2-Observer livedata object

```
viewModel.msg.observe(activity!!, Observer {
     Log.i(TAG,it)
})
```

3- remove observer

```
override fun onStop() {
    super.onStop()
    viewModel.msg.removeObservers(activity!!)
}
```

This code is working fine with me, but I wondering if my code is correct and working probably?
thanks in advance

Comment: You should observe livedata using fragments lifecycle, you will still have the shared `ViewModel` object since you already fetch it from activity, but you won't need to manually remove observers. If your fragment is undergoing detachment/reattachment you might consider using `viewLifecycleOwner` instead.

Comment: Try not removing observer in onStop() .

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is a common mistake we do while using live-data in fragment. Using `this`/`activity` on fragment can be duplicate. You should use `viewLifecycleOwner` for livedata observing in fragment.

```
viewModel.msg.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer {
            Log.i(TAG,it)
        })
```

For more information, read this article https://medium.com/@cs.ibrahimyilmaz/viewlifecycleowner-vs-this-a8259800367b

You don't need to remove the observer manually.

Comment: using viewLifecycleOwner :  after logging it value i'm getting Failure(isNetWorkError=false, errorCode=null, errorBody=null)  but 
Http client logging proper response with 200 Ok . Didn't get where it went wrong ? Any suggestions

Comment: ViewLifecycleOwner should not hamper in your response. Please recheck your use case. Any fallback or exception may be throwing the failure.

Answer (score 1):

Why you are adding the observer to the fragment with the activity lifecycle? If you have some logic that needs to be executed when fragment is not active, add it to your activity. So instead of what you have, you need:

```
viewModel.msg.observe(this, Observer {
    Log.i(TAG, it)
})
```

What happens in your case is that each time you reopen your fragment, you attach a new observer with the same lifecycle, which seems to be an error. Livedata observers were specifically designed so that you don't have to write code for handling lifecycles manually.

Comment: okay, but it throws this exception 
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot add the same observer with different lifecycles
what should i do ?